BigQuery , Connected Sheet gets blank while scripts connected to it running
I have a query and couple of scripts from 2 different sheets connected to it. After couple of hours later Connected sheet gets refreshed, the scripts run and update the sheets with the data from this connected sheet. However the connected sheet gets blank every time it reaches to the 3rd "function". I don't understand, where the problem is, the query or the scripts?.. Someone told me that the "unstable queries" can cause this but I cannot find what's wrong with it. Do you have any ideas?
WITH base_data AS (
  SELECT
    SalesPerson.CountryName,    
    SalesPerson.FullName, 
    Campaign.TypeLevel3, 
    Opportunity.Id AS OpportunityId,
    Opportunity.Code AS OpportunityCode,
    DeliveredOrder.Name AS OrderName,
    DeliveredOrder.Id AS OrderID,
    DeliveredOrder.LineItemId, 
    DeliveredOrder.LineItemName,
    Opportunity.NonStandardProducts, 
    Opportunity.PrimaryKPI, 
    BookedOrder.StartTime, 
    BookedOrder.EndTime, 
    BookedOrder.LineItemStartTime, 
    BookedOrder.LineItemEndTime, 
    BookedOrder.RateTypeCode, 
    BookedOrder.NetEurRate, 
    BookedOrder.FulFilmentItemStatus, 
    DeliveredImpressions,
    DeliveredClicks,
    DeliveredNetEurRevenue,
    DeliveredOrder.DeliveryIndicatorPct,
    BookedOrder.IsOverbookedYn, 
    BookedOrder.AdServer, 
    DeliveredOrder.LineItemPriority,
    DeliveredOrder.DeliveryRateType,
    DeliveredOrder.ImpressionsGoal, 
    Product.Subcategory, 
    DeliveredOrder.FrequencyCaps,
    TargetCountry.Name AS TargetCountryName,
    DeliveredOrder.LineItemStatus,
    DeliveryDate
  FROM `XXX_BookedDeliveredV2_*`
  WHERE 
    _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    AND SalesPerson.SalesTeamRegion = 'EMEA'
    AND SalesPersonSalesOffice.IsReseller = FALSE
    AND SalesPersonSalesOffice.SubRegionName != 'EMEA Partner Sales' 
    AND Campaign.TypeLevel3 != 'Labels'
    AND BookedOrder.AdServer IN ('DFP', 'Megaphone', 'Megaphone (MTM)')
    AND BookedOrder.FulFilmentItemStatus IN ('Inactive', 'Paused', 'Ready', 'Completed', 'Delivering')
    AND (DATE(BookedOrder.LineItemEndTime) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
         OR BookedOrder.LineItemEndTime >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
),

filtered_data AS (
  SELECT
    CountryName,    
    FullName, 
    TypeLevel3, 
    OpportunityId,
    OpportunityCode,
    OrderName,
    OrderID,
    LineItemId, 
    LineItemName,
    NonStandardProducts, 
    PrimaryKPI, 
    StartTime, 
    EndTime, 
    LineItemStartTime, 
    LineItemEndTime, 
    RateTypeCode, 
    NetEurRate, 
    FulFilmentItemStatus, 
    SUM(DeliveredImpressions) AS DeliveredImpressions, 
    SUM(DeliveredClicks) AS DeliveredClicks,
    SUM(DeliveredNetEurRevenue) AS DeliveredNetRevenue,
    AVG(DeliveryIndicatorPct) AS DeliveryIndicatorPct,
    IsOverbookedYn, 
    AdServer, 
    LineItemPriority,
    DeliveryRateType,
    ImpressionsGoal, 
    Subcategory, 
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT ARRAY_TO_STRING(FrequencyCaps, ', '), ', ') AS FrequencyCaps,
    TargetCountryName,
    LineItemStatus,
    MIN(IF(DeliveredImpressions > 0, DeliveryDate, NULL)) AS first_delivery_date
  FROM base_data
  GROUP BY
    CountryName, FullName, TypeLevel3, OpportunityId, OpportunityCode, OrderName, OrderID, 
    LineItemId, LineItemName, NonStandardProducts, PrimaryKPI, StartTime, EndTime, 
    LineItemStartTime, LineItemEndTime, RateTypeCode, NetEurRate, FulFilmentItemStatus, 
    IsOverbookedYn, AdServer, LineItemPriority, DeliveryRateType, ImpressionsGoal, 
    Subcategory, TargetCountryName, LineItemStatus
)

SELECT
  fd.*,
  Reach.ReachLifetime,
  IFNULL(insights.events_started, 0) AS events_started,
  IFNULL(insights.events_ended, 0) AS events_ended,
  IFNULL(insights.events_ended / NULLIF(insights.events_started, 0), 0) AS CR
FROM filtered_data fd
LEFT JOIN `XXX_AdsReachFrequencyV2` AS Reach
  ON fd.LineItemId = Reach.DeliveredOrder.LineItemId
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    line_item_id,
    SUM(events_started) AS events_started,
    SUM(events_ended) AS events_ended
  FROM `XXX_active_media_quartiles_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  GROUP BY line_item_id
) AS insights
  ON fd.LineItemId = CAST(insights.line_item_id AS STRING)


Hi @Pelin, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

If you can run this query in BigQuery UI but Connected Sheets cannot handle that - it might be an Apps Script limitation or anything similar.
To check this out - you can try other tools like OWOX, or Coupler, or anything else to query your BigQuery data into Sheets.
